# Getting null array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

i have a database named "`products`" which has a column "`categories`". This table contain four category of products namely `electronic`,`Decoration`,`clothes` and `vehicle`. My target to show these `category` with their `count` i`e:if there are four products belongs to category electronic, then output should be like this :electronic=4` and so on

My code

```
    public function category()
      {
      $arrayCategorys = ['electronic','Decoration','clothes','vehicle'];
      $data = [];
      foreach($arrayCategorys as $arrayCategory)
       {
      $sql = "SELECT  count(id) FROM products WHERE   categories='$arrayCategory'";
      $records = \DB::select($sql); 
      $data = array_merge_recursive($data, [

                  "{$arrayCategory}" =>isset($records[0]->count),

            ]);
      $data=array_filter($data);
      dd($data);
      }
 }
```

I want show output like this

```
'electronic'=>'4',

'Decoration'=>'2',

'clothes'=>'2',
```

`'vehicle'=>'1'` according to data in database
but iam getting nothing ,`[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY` your categories like this way when you `COUNT`

```
SELECT categories,COUNT(*)  
FROM products 
GROUP BY categories;
```

**For Idea:** http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

**EDIT:** Though i am not familiar with laravel5 syntax but this may work for you

```
$result = DB::table('products')
            ->select('products.categories', 
                      DB::raw('count(products.id) as category_count')
                    )
            ->orderBy('products.id', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('products.categories')
            ->get();
```

Comment: how can i use query builder for this in laravel5

Comment: @RanjitKarki i have updated my answer. let me know it works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

You used `isset($records[0]->count)` but the column name for the count will be `count(id)`. Name the count as `count` like this `"SELECT  count(id) AS count FROM products WHERE   categories='$arrayCategory'"`. And you wont be able to get the count just by checking if it is set. Remove the isset and just use `$records[0]->count`. The code should look like:

```
 public function category()
 {
      $arrayCategorys = ['electronic','Decoration','clothes','vehicle'];
      $data = [];
      foreach($arrayCategorys as $arrayCategory)
       {
      $sql = "SELECT  count(id) AS count FROM products WHERE   categories='$arrayCategory'";
      $records = \DB::select($sql); 
      $data = array_merge_recursive($data, [

                  "{$arrayCategory}" =>$records[0]->count,

            ]);
      $data=array_filter($data);
      dd($data);
      }
 }
```